# Using neo4j, how to search all nodes for those that match a property.value regular expression

Tags: neo4j, cypher

With neo4j latest updates also using REST API or WEB-ADMIN

What's the best way for search all nodes for those `pattern.matches(property name)` and `pattern.matches(property value)`?

For example find all nodes that matches a property:

```
value: .*My\sDesired.*
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`start n=node(*) where n.property =~ value return n`

see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-where.html#where-regular-expressions